# Spring Java based configuration and Resources issue

Tags: java, css, spring

I have a problem with loading css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="<spring:url value="resources/materialize/css/materialize.min.css"/>"
 type="text/css"/>
```

using:

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Here where my css files

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may help (Work for me):

==> Spring

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/")
            .setCachePeriod(31556926);
}
```

==> JSP

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<c:url value="/materialize/css/materialize.min.css"/>' />
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: the css file can't be loaded

Comment: try to delete the Apache tomcat server and add it again.

Comment: and then try this - <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/materialize/css/materialize.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">